# Windows Phone 8 can't handle HTTP code 301 in BackgroundFileTransfer or BackgroundAudioPlayer?

Tags: http, windows-phone-8

I am using the BackgroundFileTransfer method to download large audio files in Windows Phone. Everything works great on Windows Phone 7, but on Windows Phone 8 it seems I get TransferError = "The HTTP network provider returned an error" for some URLs and I see the status code being 301 (Moved permanently).

I also get SystemException if I try to open this URL in the BackgroundAudioPlayer (which also works on WP7).

So doesn't WP8 know how to handle HTTP code 301?

Comment: This might be by design. Would you want a background application jumping from domain to domain without your input?

Comment: @RichardA. I expect though that HTTP code 302 is probably handled though

Comment: Yes, that is what I expect from a HTTP client. And I would also not expect regression from WP7. In HTTP there's a limit to the hops you can do wrt. code 301.

Comment: @Earlz Yes, HTTP 302 seems to work fine.

Comment: Then somehow file a bug with Microsoft. They didn't implement the HTTP standard correctly heh. Since it's a permanent redirect though, you should be able to just take the URL it redirects to and use that

Comment: I could file a bug. Do you know where I can do that? I might also add that it seems this issue is not consistent with all 301 responses, but I have two URLs that return 301 and I can reproduce it 100% with them on WP8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more investigation and I have some more info; this issue not related to HTTP 301 at all but HTTPS connection. Both of the URLs that do not work are behind HTTPS.

WP8 doesn't even try to fetch anything as it send "FIN, ACK" after the handshake. WP8 just gives up. WP7 on the other hand sends "SYN" as it should and starts to download the file (after receiving HTTP 301).

I have let MS know about this issue: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/f4cc446d-534c-496f-86e2-d21e72001177. Let's see if anything happens.